# How can I find auth user id from jQuery foreach loop?

Tags: jquery

I wanna get auth user id on jquery foreach looping . But not working my codes.

Codes :

```
 let user="<?= Auth::User()->id?>";    
$.each(data.postlikes, function(key, postliker){                                                                         
     if(postliker.user_id==user){                                 
                       var targetfound= postliker.user_id;
                     }                          
                               
});

   if(targetfound){
         $('.posted-area').append('<button class="btn-primary" id="btnLiked" onclick="btnUnLikefunction()"> Liked!</button>');
 }else{
      $('.posted-area').append('<button class="btn-danger" id="btnLike" onclick="btnLikefunction()">Like </button>');
}
```

Comment: Share more details, please make sure your php file data for Auth::user()->id

Comment: check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74324722/how-can-i-found-post-liker-at-laravel-controller-and-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had got a solution :

If I declare public function at Post Model then it works:

```
public function authpostliker()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PostLike::class)->where('user_id', auth()->id());
}
```